# How to get the value of radio button in ColdFusion?

Tags: forms, get, coldfusion, radio-button

I can't find a simple tutorial to help me do this task. Basically I need to assign the value of radio button and pass it to the next page through session. This is my code for the radio button input.

```
<input type="radio" name="statReqYN" id="statReqYN-0" value="Yes" checked="checked"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="statReqYN" id="statReqYN-1" value="No"> No
```

After that, I will set the value of button:

```
<cfif isdefined("form.newProdYN") and form.newProdYN is "No"> 
<cfset form.newProdNY = "No">
</cfif>
```

Lastly, I will pass it to the next page of the same session through the submit button:

```
<cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
<cfset session.checkout.input = {
newProdNY=form.newProdNY}>
<cflocation url="formcomplete.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>
```

But when I try to get the value with #session.checkout.input.newProdYN# in html, the result is undefined. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I do not understood what you are trying to do but on form submit, you can check for variable form.stateReqYN and you will get value of radio button.

Comment: Radio buttons are only submitted if they are checked. So if you are trying to set a default value, if the field is NOT defined, then the cfif logic is wrong. It assigns "No" if that field IS defined and already has a value of "No", which does not make much sense. The correct expression is `<cfif NOT isDefined("form.newProdYN")>` (or better yet use `structKeyExists`). That said, [`cfparam`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfparam) is probably the most appropriate, as it was designed for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear as there are variables that are not being shown in your code. 
Generally, with radio and checkbox fields, your receiving form should have a default value set. I do this by doing something along the lines of:

`<cfparam name="FORM.statReqYN" default="no">`

This way you can always use the variable. So in your case, I would have this as the whole template:

```
<cfparam name="form.statReqYN" default="No">
<cfparam name="form.newProdYN" default="Yes">

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="statReqYN" id="statReqYN-0" value="Yes" checked="checked"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="statReqYN" id="statReqYN-1" value="No"> No

    <button type="submit" name="newProdYN" value="Yes">Submit</button>

</form>


<cfif form.newProdYN IS 'Yes'>
    <cfset session.checkout.input.newProduNY = form.newProdYN >
    <cfset session.checkout.input.statReqYN = form.statReqYN >
    <cflocation url="formcomplete.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>
```

I hope this makes a bit more sense?

Comment: *<cfif form.newProdYN IS 'Yes'>* @DeDeDeDe - Though obviously your actual logic may differ slightly. It looks like yours is tied to some validation/error checking instead.